# Getting all related tables of a specific table in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, database-schema

I have an application implemented in laravel in which I want to add record rules security feature.

The story is that admin selects a resource(object type) in the system as well as some user roles(groups) and then specifies rules for actions on that resource(object type). Therefore if a user has for example update permission on some resource he is limited to update the records that match the rule.

I can let the admin write a domain in raw sql format inside a textarea for each rule. But for more user-friendliness Its better to show the column names of the resource tables and regarding the foreign-keys in the database list the **tables that have relations with this resource table** because admin may specify rules like this for example:

```
[resource.parent.user_id = user.id]
```

I can get the table columns simply by:

```
Schema::getColumnListing('users')
```

In addition to the above, what I wish is something like these:

```
Schema::getChildTables('users');
```

and:

```
Schema::getParentTables('users')
```

and:

```
Schema::getTablesWithManyToManyRelation('users')
```

and the output:

```
[
'courses',
'posts',
...
]
```

My question is that do we have such thing in Laravel Eloquent or we should get the show on the road? ;)

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: you can get by mysql query then use in your code...

Comment: Thanks @Zafar, this is exactly what I can, But not what I want.